# OpenMP handling heterogeneous platform

Tags: android, c++, arm, openmp

I am working on optimizing a library using OpenMP. I benchmark the library on two different platforms:

- My working x86 computer that has 4 Intel Core i5-6500 CPU @3.20GHz
- A rooted Honor 5c phone that has 4 ARM Cortex-A53 @2.0GHz and 4 ARM Cortex-A53 @1.7GHz

In order to execute code on the phone, I just cross compile everything on my workstation and control the benchmarks with scripts that use adb. However, I had some issues getting everything optimized as I wanted i.e. close to an 8 theoretical speedup on the phone. The explanation would be the CPU usage when performing a simple Matrix multiplication operation. I have this basic code that helps me measuring the usage :

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>

// For custom types
#include "smu/core.h"

int main(void) {
  long double cpua[4], cpub[4], loadavg;
  FILE *fp;
  char dump[50];

  // Setting matrices
  int32 nr = 500;
  int32 nc = 500;
  float32 *a = (float32*)malloc(nr * nc * sizeof(float32));
  float32 *b = (float32*)malloc(nr * nc * sizeof(float32));
  float32 *c = (float32*)malloc(nr * nc * sizeof(float32));
  for (int32 i = 0; i < nr; ++i) {
    float32 *adata = a + i * nc;
    float32 *bdata = b + i * nc;
    int32 cache_nc = nc;
    for (int32 j = 0; j < cache_nc; ++j) {
      adata[j] = (float32)rand() / (float32)RAND_MAX * 100.;
      bdata[j] = (float32)rand() / (float32)RAND_MAX * 100. - 50.;
    }
  }

  for(;;) {
    fp = fopen("/proc/stat", "r");
    fscanf(fp,"%*s %Lf %Lf %Lf %Lf", &cpua[0], &cpua[1], &cpua[2], &cpua[3]);
    fclose(fp);
    for (int32 i = 0; i < nr ; ++i) {
      int32 cache_nc = nc;
      float32 *adata = a + i * cache_nc;
      float32 *cdata = c + i * cache_nc;
      for (int32 j = 0; j < cache_nc; ++j) {
        cdata[j] = 0.;
        for (int32 k = 0; k < cache_nc; ++k)
          cdata[j] += adata[k] * b[k * cache_nc + j];
      }
    }
    fp = fopen("/proc/stat", "r");
    fscanf(fp,"%*s %Lf %Lf %Lf %Lf", &cpub[0], &cpub[1], &cpub[2], &cpub[3]);
    fclose(fp);
    loadavg = ((cpub[0] + cpub[1] + cpub[2]) - (cpua[0] + cpua[1] + cpua[2])) /
        ((cpub[0] + cpub[1] + cpub[2] + cpub[3]) - (cpua[0] + cpua[1] + cpua[2] + cpua[3]));
    printf("CPU usage             : %Lf\n", loadavg);

    fp = fopen("/proc/stat", "r");
    fscanf(fp,"%*s %Lf %Lf %Lf %Lf", &cpua[0], &cpua[1], &cpua[2], &cpua[3]);
    fclose(fp);
  #pragma omp parallel for num_threads(8) schedule(dynamic, 1)
    for (int32 i = 0; i < nr ; ++i) {
      int32 cache_nc = nc;
      float32 *adata = a + i * cache_nc;
      float32 *cdata = c + i * cache_nc;
      for (int32 j = 0; j < cache_nc; ++j) {
        cdata[j] = 0.;
        for (int32 k = 0; k < cache_nc; ++k)
          cdata[j] += adata[k] * b[k * cache_nc + j];
      }
    }
    fp = fopen("/proc/stat", "r");
    fscanf(fp,"%*s %Lf %Lf %Lf %Lf", &cpub[0], &cpub[1], &cpub[2], &cpub[3]);
    fclose(fp);
    loadavg = ((cpub[0] + cpub[1] + cpub[2]) - (cpua[0] + cpua[1] + cpua[2])) /
        ((cpub[0] + cpub[1] + cpub[2] + cpub[3]) - (cpua[0] + cpua[1] + cpua[2] + cpua[3]));
    printf("CPU usage with OpenMP : %Lf\n", loadavg);
  }

  free(a);
  free(b);
  free(c);

  return(0);
}
```

On my x86 workstation, the results are as expected:

```
CPU usage             : 0.267606
CPU usage with OpenMP : 1.000000
CPU usage             : 0.271429
CPU usage with OpenMP : 1.000000
```

While on the phone it seems, it cannot get all the cores at once:

```
CPU usage             : 0.143388
CPU usage with OpenMP : 0.495968
CPU usage             : 0.129955
CPU usage with OpenMP : 0.496626
```

That is strange as the No OpenMP usage let me think as only 1 on 8 cores is used. I checked the OpenMP platform info and he can see correctly 8 cores on the Honor 5c.

My questions are:

- How OpenMP handles that kind of asynchronous platforms ?
- Is there any solution in order to get close to 100% core usage anytime, anywhere ?
- How OpenMP handles virtualized cores (not directly related to this topic but it still interests me to have an answer to that) ?

EDIT:

I've tried to see directly in the OS how he handle the cores by executing this simple script:

```
#!/system/bin/sh
i=0
while : ; do
  i=$(($i + 1))
done
```

And even having 8 threads running it would result in maximum 50% of CPU usage.

I read this article explaining that [there could be several OS in a phone](http://www.osnews.com/story/27416/The_second_operating_system_hiding_in_every_mobile_phone) making only one of them usable. In my case it would be 1 per group of 4 cores. But then I don't understand why OpenMP would see 8 cores...

Comment: Is that C or C++? Don't spam tags.

Comment: Both. The library is C++, and it executes C++ style and C style code on the phone. Will it change the answer anyway ?

Comment: Well, does it matter that both are different languages with different behaviour for even identical source code? Of course it does. Please get the tags right on questions and don't spam tags.